# NetLogo GIS extension - create-turtles-inside polygons in NetLogo

Tags: agent-based-modeling

I am trying to create turtles within postcode boundary. I have imported the postcode shapefile in NetLogo and applied postcodes to the patches. I could create one turtle within each postcode boundary but struggling to figureout how can I create number of turtles within each postcode boundary according to the `NUM_AGENT` field from the attribute table of postcode shapefile?

The following code can successfully create one turtle per postcode.

```
  to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  set res_town gis:load-dataset "Projected_data/town_data.shp"
  set studyextent gis:load-dataset "Projected_data/Apr.asc"
  resize-world -924 924 -800 800 ; 0 gis:width-of (studyextent) - 1 0 gis:height-of (studyextent) - 1
  gis:set-drawing-color grey
  gis:draw res_town 1
  gis:draw studyarea 1
  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-union-of (gis:envelope-of res_town) (gis:envelope-of studyextent) ) 
  gis:set-coverage-minimum-threshold 0.0000001
  gis:apply-coverage res_town "POA" postcode
  ask patches [  ifelse (postcode <= 0) or (postcode >= 0)  [ ] [ set postcode 0]  ]   ; NaN fix
  let respatches patches with [postcode > 0 ]
  ask respatches [
    set postcode round (postcode)
    set pcolor 2 + postcode * 0.75
  ]
  let postcodelist ([postcode] of respatches)
  let uniquepostcodelist remove-duplicates postcodelist
  let sortedlist sort uniquepostcodelist
  print length sortedlist
  print sortedlist
  ;; create turtle for each postcode
  
  foreach  sortedlist [ x ->
    ask one-of respatches with [postcode = x] [sprout 1 [set shape "person" set size 15 ]]
  ]
  
end
```

I am not sure how to add a number of turtles per postcode according to `NUM_TURTLES` field from the postcode shapefile.

I tried using `gis:create-turtles-inside-polygon` command instead of `gis:apply-coverage` but when I type the command `gis:create-turtles-inside` it gives an error saying nothing named `gis:create-turtles-inside` has been defined. I am using exactly the same code as mentioned in the example.

```
foreach gis:feature-list-of res_town [ res-postcode -> 
    gis:create-turtles-inside res-postcode beekeepers 1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Tool extensions menu, make sure the GIS extension is updated. That worked for me.

Comment: Thank you Maurice, I will check that now. I actually, managed to create turtles from shapefile attributes using foreach loop.